# Proof involving Lagrange's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $a$ and $b$ be nonidentity elements of different orders in a group $G$ of order $155$.
Prove that the only subgroup of $G$ that contains $a$ and $b$ is $G$ itself.

What I have so far:
We know that by the Lagrange's theorem, $|a|$ and $|b|$ divide $G$. So $|a|$ and $|b|$ must be either $1,5, 31,$ or $155$. Since $a$ and $b$ are non-identity elements, their orders cannot be $1$.

Comment: Well if $|a| \neq |b|$ but they can only each be 5, 31, or 155 give us a subgroup $G'$ such that $a,b \in G'$ yet $G \neq G'$.

Comment: Notice that If one of the order is $155$, we are done. If not, one of the order $5$ and one of the order $31$. The if $H$ includes $a,b$ then order of $H$ divisible by $5$ and $31$. Then $|G|=155$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Elementary solution**

1. Because the two elements are nonidentity we have : $|a|,|b|>1$
2. Now we have $|a|,|b|\in\{5,31,155\}$ we have two cases:

   - If $|a|$ or $|b|=155$ then the group $|<a,b>|=155$ hence $<a,b>=G$
   - Otherwise $\{|a|,|b|\}=\{5,31\}$ then the group $|<a,b>|=|a||b|=155$ hence $<a,b>=G$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $S$ be a subgroup of $G$ containing $a$ and $b$. Now apply Lagrange's theorem to $a$, $b$ and $S$.

Elementary proof:

> -
>   By Lagrange's theorem, $\text{ord}(a)$ divides $|S|$ and $\text{ord}(b)$ divides $|S|$, so $\text{lcm}(\text{ord}(a),\text{ord}(b)) = 155$ divides $|S|$ so $S = G$.

Comment: I do not think that it is an hint. Op is already awere of this fact.

Comment: No he/she isn't. He applied it to G, not the subgroup.

Comment: Again I do not agree with you. But it is not important.

Comment: It seems better now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $H\le G$, and $a,b\in H$, then $|H|=5$ implies $|a|=|b|=5$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If either $|a|=155$ or $|b|=155$, then there is nothing really to prove, so assume WLOG that $|a|=5$ and $|b|=31$. Let $S$ be a subgroup containing $a$ and $b$. Using the cancellation law, show that $S$ contains the distinct elements 
$$
a^ib^j
$$
for $1\leq i\leq 5$ and $1\leq j\leq 31$. How many such elements are there?